# Placing JLabel in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I typed just any text that does not fit and JScrollPane does not work. In general, it does not show text area.

```
textArea = new JTextArea("asdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfs");
textArea.setBounds(20, 400, 130, 30);
textArea.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20));
panelHome.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use texarea in jscroll, you should use similar solution:

```
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
```

Comment: Not working `textArea = new JTextArea("asdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfasdfsdfsdfsdfsdf");
    
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    scroll.setViewportView(textArea);
    
    panelHome.add(scroll);`

Comment: @Q.One: if your code isn't working, show the updated code as an edit to your question, but best if it is a small working program, an [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check out the links).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
textArea.setBounds(20, 400, 130, 30);
```

You're constraining the size of the JTextArea to be 130 by 30, no matter what text it has, and doing this will prevent the JScrollPane from working properly. You never want to set the size of your Swing components (or use null layouts) and instead with a JTextArea want to set its rows and columns. This will allow the JTextArea to expand if need be.

Edit: as suggested by user1722245 --- 1+ to his answer.

Note that I also usually call `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on my JTextAreas so that they'll wrap the text to the next line when the need arises.

Also another important factor is the layout manager of the container, here panelHome, that you're adding your JScrollPane to as this will effect how it displays the JScrollPane and its contents.

For example, in the code below, I set the JTextArea's columns and rows properties in its constructor, I set the text areas word wrap policies, I add it to a JScrollPane's viewport view by passing it into the JScrollPane's constructor, and I add the JScrollPane to a BorderLayout-using JPanel in the CENTER position. Now when text is appended to the JTextArea, it displays the wrapped text and shows the scroll bars but only when needed.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextAreaEg extends JPanel {
    private static final int TEXTAREA_ROWS = 20;
    private static final int TEXTAREA_COLUMNS = 40;
    private static final String NONSENSE_TEXT = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "
            + "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor "
            + "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad "
            + "minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris "
            + "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure "
            + "dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum "
            + "dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat "
            + "cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia "
            + "deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TEXTAREA_ROWS, TEXTAREA_COLUMNS);

    public TextAreaEg() {
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        JButton addTextButton = new JButton(new AddTextAction("Add Text", KeyEvent.VK_A));
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(addTextButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class AddTextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddTextAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                textArea.append(NONSENSE_TEXT + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TextAreaEg mainPanel = new TextAreaEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```